# youtube-iframe-api embedd parameters stopped working

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

YouTube embed parameters stopped working for embedded videos. The embedded video is showing items that should be removed by parameter code. 
[Screenshot of YouTube embed with parameters not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KweV1.jpg)

Comment: Please provide more information. Your question is way too ambiguous.

Comment: If you look at the screenshot you'll see the items that were showing on the video embed that should have been removed by using the proper YouTube Embed Parameters...in this case: ?rel=0&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3

Comment: Regardless, the issue resolved itself so everything is working as it should now.